# Progressbar setProgress not working on UI Thread

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar, ui-thread

Am trying to update the progressbar while appending values to recyclerview. Even after created a new thread setProgress method is not correctly working. Am attaching my piece of code here

```
        progress_horizontal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progress_horizontal.setProgress(0);
        progress_horizontal.setMax(titles.length);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                            itemListsList.add(new ListItemRadioLists(titles[i], false));
                            progress_horizontal.setProgress(i);
                        }
                        rv_search.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                        progress_horizontal.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
```

Can anyone help me figure out this problem.?

Comment: how are u initialising the handler ?

Comment: @SantanuSur     private Handler handler = new Handler(); globally

Comment: Ah ! it loops very fast and u are not able to figure out the progress , to figure out the progress there should be some `delay` before `setProgress` which is not there !

Comment: @SantanuSur I made a delay by using Thread.sleep method. But still UI is not updating for the progressBar

Comment: initialise `handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` and also u cannot make the `mainThread sleep` !

Comment: @SantanuSur I added as per your suggestion but its still not working..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206277/discussion-between-cyril-david-and-santanu-sur).

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59457746/cant-use-setbackgroundresource-when-using-thread-sleep-on-click). The root cause of your issue is the same.