# Why value of only last iteration(999) is printed in the text field ? I want all numbers to be printed before getting replaced by next number

Tags: java, android, iteration

I am new to `android studio` and want to overcome from this problem.

It gonna help me a lot while creating some future apps like , stopwatch, timer etc etc.

Thanks in advance !!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText k;
    private Button start;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        k=findViewById(R.id.kf);
        start=findViewById(R.id.startf);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for(int i=1;i<1000;i++)
                {

                    k.setText(String.valueOf(i) );


                }
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: Because this happens incredibly fast. You expect to see all the numbers after each other, but this code runs for less than 1 millisecond. The question is: why would you expect anything else than this?

Comment: You can add a long(human percievable delay) i n beween the counts.

Comment: A delay is necessary, but insufficient to fix the problem. This loop blocks the UI thread, and the UI thread is needed to redraw the `TextView`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59457746/cant-use-setbackgroundresource-when-using-thread-sleep-on-click) for a related question.

Comment: The upper limit should be **+1** (off by one, positive). Because it stops as soon as it reaches it, skipping the iteration. So, `i<1001`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @f1sh already mentioned in the comments your for loop is executing at such a speed that all you see is the final value. For such cases in `android` one of the best solutions is to make use of `Handler` for posting delayed functions without blocking the UI.

So for showing 1 to 999 you can try something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText k;
private Button start;
int count;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    k=findViewById(R.id.kf);
    start=findViewById(R.id.startf);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (count < 1000) {
                k.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                count++;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
        }
    };
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count = 1;
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

this will keep changing the text in `TextView` with a 1 second delay, you can change the delay as needed by setting the milliseconds in runnable.

You can even use a countdown timer for this purpose but its more like a workaround and requires you to calculate the correct time etc. 
For example displaying 1 to 10 would be something like this:

```
...
count = 1;
new CountDownTimer(11000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            count++;
        }
        public void onFinish() {
        }
    }.start();
```

here you are displaying the value every 1 second for 11 seconds

Comment: Helped a lot !! Thank you so much :)

Comment: had forgotten about this post, well if this cleared your issues, you may accept this as the answer and let others know your question was resolved.